# I am a sockpuppet; may I exist if I have a real purpose?

Tags: discussion, sock-puppets

I am a sockpuppet account of [Josh, AKA The Unhandled Exception](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/131541/the-unhandled-exception). I am going to help him test the XMPP chat integration system he's building.

Am I allowed to exist? I promise to behave, and never leave Meta or Meta's chat. If so, may I please have enough rep to chat?

EDIT BY JOSH: I have drawn a freehand circle for my sock: 
[image]

Comment: I forbid it. Sock puppets are the most horrible things imaginable.

Comment: Also I see absolutely no freehand circles.

Comment: I can only give you half, just cause you're clean

Comment: @Toronto: He can't draw freehand circles. He has no hands...

Comment: @Josh: I'm just a head in a jar and I still manage to draw circles. He has no excuse.

Comment: Toronto: Heads are better than feet :-) I have drawn a FHC on his behalf.

Comment: I would upvote, since you are good enough not to skip half the issue and upvote yourself. But I'm too busy enjoying the sad existence at being *just* shy of 20 reputation.

Comment: I am crying @Grace!

Comment: 3 seconds... this new alert system is quite fast. Neat.

Comment: @Grace: I feel that, by **not** upvoting my sockpuppet, I am demonstrating that I have honorable intentions here!

Comment: Whach out or you're sock puppet will accumulate more rep than you've got.

Comment: @Josh'sSocks, In what ways are you used to test XMPP integration?

Comment: Related MSO post: [What are the rules governing multiple accounts?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/388984/11107541)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

<sup>Warning label: the following post is written tongue-in-cheek. Read carefully.</sup>

I haven't been banned for it yet. And only a small handful of my accounts have been unceremoniously deleted. So I say, go for it!

To clarify: I do stupid, dodgy stuff with my sockpuppets, including (but not limited to) posting bogus answers, impersonating other users, impersonating other sockpuppets, and answering JavaScript questions. If you do these things, you may well find your accounts removed. If you abuse the voting system (voting up posts from one account using another account, voting twice on the same post using multiple accounts, awarding bounties from one account to another, etc.) you may well find your accounts merged and/or deleted, and yourself suspended. If you avoid such behavior, and are careful to avoid any obvious overlap between your accounts, you'll be fine.

Comment: "small handful of my accounts have been unceremoniously deleted. So I say, go for it!" Wait, why would you have more than one?

Comment: @TheLQ: various reasons. Some I use just to have a low-rep account for testing behavior that only exists for low-rep users, or to remind myself what answering questions is like for the same. One was created to re-ask questions that I didn't feel comfortable editing. And some were created for jokes on Meta.

Comment: Wow. I had no idea you had so many sock puppets. I dare say you're a... *socks machine*.

Comment: Ouch. @Jon. Just... ouch.

Comment: Thanks @Shog9! I promise I won't abuse the voting system.

Comment: "I do stupid, dodgy stuff with my sockpuppets, including ...  answering JavaScript questions. If you do these things, you may well find your accounts removed." --- wait, what?

Comment: Should probably be read with an implicit "most or all of the above"...

Comment: So you're actually allowed to have multiple accounts provided that they don't involve any cross interactions with each other?

Comment: There's no explicit support for it, but provided you don't do anything harmful there's no hard rule *against* it either, @puretppc.

Comment: @Shog9 This is because I have classmates at my school who are interested in Stack for help. I've warned them that if they attempted to touch any of my posts, they would get banned and vice versa. I'm hoping that they could ask their own Q's

Comment: You shouldn't have to worry - just remind them that this *isn't* a social network: vote for posts that are useful, not people who you know. @puretppc

Comment: "To clarify: I do stupid, dodgy stuff with my sockpuppets, including (but not limited to) posting bogus answers, impersonating other users, impersonating other sockpuppets, and answering JavaScript questions." That's hilarious!

Comment: @Shog9 if it is the school's wireless network wouldn't you also be able to do some form of reverse IP lookup to determine the posts are only partially occurring at a public location? After all, friends at school will also end up using their home internet for stack exchange as well. Honestly, I've never understood why people can use that excuse nowadays. I might go ask a question about this fact.