# Long names cut off in questions and answers

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, design, user-interface, user-card

*The Unhandled Exception*'s name is cut off in this [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65604/i-am-a-sockpuppet-may-i-exist-if-i-have-a-real-purpose) and in the answer too. The last 'n' looks like an 'r'.

Using Firefox 3.6.6.

Examples:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Jeff will get furious if someone finds a bug in this post, screen caps it and circles the error in red...

Comment: I take that as a challenge to find some bug with this post! `;-)`

Comment: [Poor C. M. Sperberg-McQueen](http://images.jenserat.de/2013-07-07_2351.png), called him McQueer until I was told that this is probably not his real name.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Correct, there's a fixed amount of space, and some names are longer than can fit in the space, so it is unavoidably truncated.

We allow ~26 character names, so your name could be

MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM

or

iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii

Notice difference in length.

Comment: I'm now prompted to say this: Monospace fonts FTW.

Comment: Then there should be a name length restriction. There is no point to have a long name if you "cannot" use it.

Comment: @gotqn read the answer again, you missed "We allow ~26 character names".

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Yes, you are right. I have understood this wrong.