# Moderator Info Panel Bug

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, moderator-tools

<strike>Two</strike> One very minor bug<strike>s</strike> in the UI for the moderator history listing on Math.SE (though I wonder if the same problem happens on other SEs).

[image: Image of the moderator panel for a day report]

1. <strike>As you can see, one of my fellow moderator's name is a bit on the long side, and his diamond mark became a wedge.</strike> (*Edit: as Cody indicated in the comments, this is by design.*)
2. This is the listing for activities for the **day**. There's no way I could post **389** comments on Meta in one day. I don't even know if Jon Skeet can do that. Those numbers on the last two columns appear to be *life-time totals*, judging from the fact that changing the display to "month", "quarter", and "all" does not affect the number displayed in those columns.

Comment: For your number 1: Yeah, names that are too long are truncated. This is [by design](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65606/long-names-cut-off-in-questions-and-answers), not a bug. That one just happens to be the perfect length so as to truncate half of the diamond. Not sure what you suggest doing about it. You can either ask Mariano to shorten his name, or write a bunch of code to truncate the name *before* the diamond, and all for minimal gain. You knew who he was...

Comment: @Cody: okay, I wasn't aware that was by design. Thanks for the link.

Comment: @Cody: Or place the diamond before the name

Comment: @Yoda That'd just make the name cut-off at the Z instead, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since these stats are currently only easily available from meta for all time I have removed them from display for filtering by quarter, month, or day - they will only show when you click ALL.  This will be deployed later tonight.