# My name is too long to be contained

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, user-interface, display-names

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Long names cut off in questions and answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65606/long-names-cut-off-in-questions-and-answers)

See [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109030/my-name-is-too-long-to-be-contained) question.

Or alternatively, [How to convince a teammate, who sees oneself as senior, to learn SVN conceptual basics?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/113636/how-to-convince-a-teammate-who-sees-oneself-as-senior-to-learn-svn-conceptual-b) for the original discovery.

Apparently poster signature block clips the overflowing text.

Comment: You mean it leaves `Courageous Anonymous` visible and hides `Coward`? Looks like a feature to me :)

Comment: Your name is legion?