# Meta-meta - what should I do about a meta question tagged as status-bydesign that I believe is wrong?

Tags: discussion, tags, meta

Looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15139962/changing-caret-cursor-position) on SO I noticed that the user name in two of the answers ("William Bettridge-Radford") is cut off mid-character on the right hand side. It is quite a long user name but I still don't think it should be cut off mid-character - if truncated the truncation should preserve whole characters, and there should be some indication that it has been truncated, like "William Bettridge-Rad..." or similar.

So I came to ask about this here and discovered [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109030/my-name-is-too-long-to-be-contained) which has been closed as a duplicate of [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65606/long-names-cut-off-in-questions-and-answers) which in turn has been tagged as status-bydesign.

I don't think this issue should be closed as status-bydesign - yes, I understand that if you have 26 characters and a proportional font, you are more likely to have to end up truncating something if it has "wide" characters in it, but there's no excuse for truncating it in the middle of a character, nor for failing to indicate visually to the user that they are looking at something that has been truncated.

So: how should I deal with this? If I open a new question it will just be closed as a duplicate. Is it OK to take the status-bydesign tag off the original question, effectively to "re-open" the bug?

Comment: Bounties is one way to go.

Comment: Then essentially your question is different, I'd say. Perhaps simply phrase it "I understand that this is status-by-design, but my "feature request" is to visually indicate the overflow using ...." etc. etc?

Comment: If you see wrong status applied you can flag it choose "other" and explain.

Answer (score 4):

You found a question about how names are truncated when they are too long.

But that's not what you consider to be a bug. Your objection is to names being truncated *in the middle of a character*. Therefore, [as Bart says](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170222/meta-meta-what-should-i-do-about-a-meta-question-tagged-as-status-bydesign-tha#comment503398_170222), **you have a separate question--you should go ahead and post that separately.**

If you post a new question and clearly explain how it is different from [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109030/my-name-is-too-long-to-be-contained) and [that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65606/long-names-cut-off-in-questions-and-answers), it won't be closed as a duplicate (or at least *shouldn't* be closed as a duplicate).

[That question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65606/long-names-cut-off-in-questions-and-answers) *mentions* that it's cut-off mid-letter but is not actually complaining about that; instead, it's using that to help illustrate *that it's cut off at all.* If you post a question arguing that *when names are truncated* it should be *between letters*, that's different.

(While this is a separate issue, I'm not sure I agree this is a bug, but I'll wait for you to post a question about it and explain why it is, before I assume it is not.)