# Badge numbers cut off at the right

Tags: bug, design

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Badge Holders Page Broken](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129269/badge-holders-page-broken)

Mr. Jon Skeet has been caught causing this bug.

[image]

The last digit of his bronze badge is hidden.

Edit: My system specifications

Browser: Version 22.0.1229.79 m
OS: Windows 7 Ultimate 32 bit
Screen Resolution: 1280 x 800

Comment: Which browser are you using? It looks fine on Chrome 22 (Ubuntu 12.04).

Comment: That guy again?  Nothing but a troublemaker.

Comment: Also, [a similar question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65606/long-names-cut-off-in-questions-and-answers) (about names) was marked by-design.

Comment: @animuson: every `overflow:hidden;` is the same bug? lol :)

Comment: @naveen When they say they don't care, yes. If they're not worried about names being cut off, why worry about badges being cut off? They're *even less* important.

Comment: @animuson: I have high respect for the SO team and so I am reporting this minor bug. After all they are StackOverflow :) I oggle at the site every now and then :P

Comment: No, you misinterpret the picture. That is not a partially visible digit, it's an exclamation mark. That's how many bronze badges he has.

Comment: Someone suggested that once you hit 1,000 badges the number should be shortened to 1k, 2k, 3k, etc. I can't find the question, though it is an excellent idea.

Comment: If this Skeet fellow keeps causing trouble like this, a ban might be in order...

Comment: @animuson: Well, if you insist on a long name that gets cuts off in every other field, that's your problem. It's not like Jon could simple donate a few badges to the poor...

Comment: @animuson: 1k, 2k thing is an excellent thought. I am waiting for skeet 1M and wondering whether he might get bored waiting for a change to 1.1M :)

Comment: What if you zoom out or change the default font size back to 16px? It looks fine on all browsers with default settings (cc @Dennis).

Comment: Or we may have to invent a new numbering system, in which Jon Skeet always has 1S. S for Skeetload.

Comment: BoltClock'saUnicorn: i have had zoomed by browser as i am myopic. sorry :) so my SO is not wrong after all @animuson: surprised at the closed as duplicate thing. pretty stupid you know. thats why you deleted the first comment as you realized that stackoverflow bug had  been fixed. as for your second one, Jeff Atwood said, there should be a limit for a name. its very clear that one would very likely be abusing the system unless you are someone like *Chaminda Vaas*. My point is, Jon Skeet was not abusing the system. He just got rewarded for all the services rendered. Is that a crime? lol

Comment: @naveen: The "possible duplicate" comment gets automatically inserted by the system when somebody vote to close as exact duplicate, as well as automatically deleted when the final close vote is cast.