# Am I allowed to open a new account for testing purposes?

Tags: support, multiple-accounts

Can I open a second account under a different name for testing purposes (not for community involvement?).

I want to conduct a small research on how a community behaves as a community.

Is it allowed? Will the system auto-merge it to my main account?

Comment: Related: [I am a sockpuppet, may I exist if I have a real purpose?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/65604)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no specific rule against merely having multiple accounts, *provided* you don't use extra account(s) to cheat in any way (such as voting for yourself). That said, it *is* possible your accounts could be merged, under certain circumstances.

However, I must say my spidey-sense goes off a little bit at the idea of using Stack Overflow for "research" on how a "community behaves". That sounds a little bit unconstructive, and not at all related to the purpose of the site.

Comment: No. It is not related to the purpose of the site. Like I said. I want to see how the community behaves when presented with certain conditions (Good questions, bad questions, bad answers). Not something very large or harmful to the site (as crap is deleted in seconds), but just for some data :)

Comment: I strongly urge you against doing this. As you note, 'crap' is deleted quickly - leaving you almost no actual data, but taking up the time of users moderating the site.

Comment: Aren't there enough samples of good & bad questions already? Why do you need to generate some of your own? @MadaraUchiha

Comment: @Mat: I'd like to observe this behavior in real time (I actually need some concrete data :P)

Comment: @MadaraUchiha: just hit refresh on the main page, there's loads of stuff coming continuously.

Comment: Possible solution: Make a well detailed list of the metrics you need, and the reasons for needing them. Submit this information as a request to the SE team asking for their assistance in obtaining such metrics. If they wish to oblige you now have a really good source for this information. Otherwise [Data.StackExchange.com](http://data.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Agreeing with rlemon: All the SO data was provided (under NDA) to a couple of people last year -- http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/89909 -- for mining. It's possible that, if you're convincing enough, you could also get access. @MadaraUchiha

Comment: @MadaraUchiha, if you really want to see bad questions and bad answers in real time, come hang out in the PHP tag or the jQuery tag between 4 AM and noon GMT -- 8 PM to 4 AM Pacific.  You'll get *plenty* of sample data.

Answer (score 1):

It is not forbidden to have multiple accounts. There are various reasons for doing so, for example someone using SO in work could like to have separate account for his private time researches.

But if you want to test how the community react to the bad questions, it isn't the problem with multiple accounts anymore, but the problem of asking bad questions. Doing it deliberately is considered as trolling and it hurts the community. I don't think that people would accept it and say it's OK.

And it's quite probable that some users are doing that what you have written, only they don't ask for permit. It can happen you would be suspected for some of such actions now :)