# Badges and username overlap with post timestamp in the Stack Exchange Android app

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

See question *[I am a sockpuppet, may I exist if I have a real purpose?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65604/i-am-a-sockpuppet-may-i-exist-if-i-have-a-real-purpose)*.

In the first answer, the user has enough badges that it overlaps the answer timestamp "asked xx mins ago". On the second answer, the username overlaps. I am not too sure how the display should look in this case, but it doesn't look great now.

I'm using a [Samsung Galaxy S II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_S_II) in portrait mode.

Comment: For answers the user info probably doesn't need to be indented which might reduce the number of occurrences but you might get a similar issue with very short answers in that case with the vote buttons overlapping.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks! This is fixed in the next release. It currently makes the left side two lines to wrap the reputation if it's too long, which might change in the future because it's not the cleanest UI change for that case, but the text will at least no longer overlap.

Comment: I'm still seeing long usernames overflowing with "Answered." [See here for screenshot.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/195017/168660)