# Overflow issues in Android app

Tags: bug, tags, design, android-app

Long usernames can overflow and overlap the timestamp:

[image]

And if there are too many tags, the end gets cut off:

[image]

The above [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194959/) has another tag - [language](/questions/tagged/language), which is completely missing. Tags are also sometimes cut off mid-tag.

Comment: Related: [Badges and username overlap with post timestamp in the android app](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193541/badges-and-username-overlap-with-post-timestamp-in-the-android-app)

Comment: Also related: [Questions with lots of long tags are cut off in the android app](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192598/questions-with-lots-of-long-tags-are-cut-off-in-the-android-app)