# Can I use one account to up-vote an answer from another of my accounts?

Tags: discussion, voting, sock-puppets

Like many SE users, I have multiple accounts. I am wondering if I am allowed to write an answer with one, and vote for it with another?

I suspect the answer is no, but not being one to pass on rep, I thought I should ask.

Comment: Yes, you are able to do so.  However it's not permitted even though it's possible, and when discovered all associated accounts may be punished. Since this is something that has been a problem from the beginning of Stack Overflow, the automated checks that test for this are very, very good.  I suggest you don't do it unless you don't mind losing your accounts.

Comment: "Like many SE users, I have multiple accounts." How do you know there are many SE users and they aren't all just you?

Comment: Let's not kid ourself; we're all just @BoltClock talking to himself.

Comment: @Shog9 I'm glad you told me that. It explains a lot of my behavior!

Comment: I know where I came from—but where did all you zombies come from?

Comment: @WalterMitty You will understand one day (so to speak).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Nope. If you do that, [it will end badly for you](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57682/how-should-sockpuppets-be-handled-on-stack-exchange/57685#57685).

You can have multiple accounts as long as they don't interact in any way, or do something that someone with a single account could not.

Thanks for asking first!

#### See also: [I am a sockpuppet, may I exist if I have a real purpose?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65604/i-am-a-sockpuppet-may-i-exist-if-i-have-a-real-purpose)

Answer (score 7):

**NO**

You shouldn't because you'll end up getting suspended for [Voting Fraud](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/12/vote-fraud-and-you/).

Take a look at : [What's the SO policy about having multiple user accounts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35593/whats-the-so-policy-about-having-multiple-user-accounts)