# False allegation need be falsified (?)

Tags: discussion, moderator-tools

A few days ago I read a question here reporting a mod at PSE having an alias. In the answers it was specified when and on what conditions that is considered fair, and somebody suggested the user posted a the site-meta without hesitation because deleting such a serious report would be a serious abuse.

This morning I chanced to read (with my own eyes) a post at Physics SE and I posted the following [**question**](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7255/false-allegations-need-be-falsified?noredirect=1#comment28546_7255) at the site meta:

> "The other day there was a report on Meta by somebody who either is
>   not a member here or is afraid of retaliation.
>
> This morning I personnally read a post on the main site in which
>   allegations were made that some users are aliases of a mod.
>
> Considering that 2 days ago I removed my account here, and the
>   deletion will take place in a few hours, and considering that the post
>   was visible only to precious few for just a few minutes. I think that
>   after all it is my duty and that I  only do a favour to the members
>   involved, informing them of the rumours that circulate: the poster
>   alleged that Gert, ACuriousMind, DanielSank and other users are
>   aliases of a mod.
>
> I am not mentioning the mod not because I am afraid but because he
>   surely knows the content of that post, since he or his colleagues
>   deleted it (and I don't know how many other posts).
>
> The poster at meta was very reluctant to give details, since mod are
>   entitled to have multiple accounts, but their concern was that a post
>   claiming the answer by one (supposed mod's) alias had been deleted,
>   concealing a possible conflict of interest.
>
> I think it is in the interest of the network, of the site, of the mod
>   and of all people involved, that this post is not suppressed, letting
>   a TM investigate an publish the conclusions, surely proving the
>   allegations false.
>
> It is not difficult, I suppose , since one member declares residence
>   in UK, another in Germany and another in USA.
>
> Hoping you all be grateful, I take leave from this site."

The post has been deleted after a couple of seconds.

I thought I had to report it here and see if it can be useful to the Team Managers and to the Network.

Comment: I am going to upvote this post, I will not let people from PSE cast a negative shadow on this fair report

Comment: I don't understand the title of this post at all. Also, I don't see a question here. Can you elaborate a little?

Comment: Gee, can't see why a post with a conspiracy theory making unfounded allegations about a specific moderator and multiple high-rep members of a site would be poorly received. For the record, as a moderator on Stack Overflow I can see that there is no connection whatsoever between the users listed above. There's also no harm in having an alternate account, as long as you don't use it to do things that you couldn't do with a single account (vote twice, vote for yourself, astroturf comments, etc.).

Comment: @BradLarson, how do you/we know *that* is not happening? Isn't always best to clarify false allegations, in the members' own interest, since these rumors have wide circulations?

Comment: It looks more likely to me that *you* are using socks here to support your position. If your posts on their meta are removed that quickly, I expect that there I'd much more to this than you're telling.

Comment: I have no idea what is going on, and nobody here on MSE can see the whole picture. Only moderators of the site and Community Managers can, so  that's exactly what you have the "contact us" link in the footer.

Comment: Similar post already deleted on meta.physics: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/7255/false-allegations-need-be-falsified (10K and mods only).

Comment: I'm guessing the question that you read here was http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/269600/is-it-appropriate-for-a-mod-to-use-sockpuppets but it would help if link to whichever earlier question you read here was linked to in your question.

Answer (score 29):

**The situation.**

During the past day or so, there have been multiple posts on Physics Stack Exchange (not meta, but the main site) declaring that multiple high-rep users on Physics are all sockpuppets of another high-rep (non-mod) user, whom we'll call user X. These have been posted under different accounts and in slightly different formats, but they all call user X a psychopath and say that he should be removed.

The second of these posts said

> If you see this message save it immediately because [User X] will delete the topic soon.
>
> Do not be discouraged by the erratic comments of the users: [User 1], [Moderator 1], [User 2]. The real name of the man hiding behind these sock-puppets is [User X]. He is a known psychopathic troublemaker on stackexchange.com. He will be soon fired. Letters have been already sent to all members of the StackExchange management team to inform them that instead of aiding people, because he is paid to help, [User X] is throwing messages like "we discourage this kind of question" or posts a bogus answer using one name and then writes a highly appreciative comment masquerading as a different person to mislead people and make them believe his answers are of high quality when in reality they are just trash. I forgot to mention the numerous pluses [User X] gives to his sock-puppets using other sock-puppets and the numerous minuses [User X], using the same trick, gives to others, especially to people who answer questions correctly, to discredit them.

**Response**

You seem to want there to be an investigation to show that these allegations are false. I don't see why such an investigation is necessary. There is no evidence to support the claims, and it seems quite likely that the users who posted these are annoyed because their questions were closed by, among others, user X.

Without coming off as harsh. . . Come on. This is not worth investigating. All the content in it is of dubious quality, too.

Additionally, in the context of the other posts, your meta question made it seem an awful lot like you are one of the *actual* sockpuppet users making accusations. I actually still think that that's a possibility. So given that you're asking for the exact same thing as the actual sockpuppet complainers, it makes sense that your post was deleted. You might be just another one of the sockpuppets.

If you're *really* concerned, you can use the [Contact Us](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) link in the footer. Ostensibly, though, the user who brought up all this in the first place has contacted Stack Exchange (see the "letters"). So if you give an credence whatsoever to what s/he says, then you'll agree that, in theory, Stack Exchange already knows about this.

**Other notes**

You wrote

> since mod are entitled to have multiple accounts

This is not the case. Moderators aren't given any more leeway with sockpuppet accounts than anyone else is. However, see [How should sockpuppets be handled on Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57682/how-should-sockpuppets-be-handled-on-stack-exchange?lq=1).

Comment: User X is a badass user name.  I'm going to create a sockpuppet just to call him User X.