# Are mods allowed to use secondary account(s) to cast non-decisive votes?

Tags: discussion, moderators, abuse, sock-puppets, multiple-accounts

<sub>(Motivated by [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/361125/259412), now falsely dupe-closed question.)</sub>

Mods can not cast non-decisive votes. [Sometimes they would like to](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/41062/259412). Sometimes they would like to talk with users so that the diamond does not alter their communication context. Sometimes they might like to feel the site as an ordinary mortal do.

Shog (CM at the time) says [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/57685/259412):

> If the second account allows you to do something on the site that your normal account would be prevented from doing, it is abuse.

On this definition, doing these as a mod, likely qualifies as an abuse: because the normal account of the mod is prevented to act as an ordinary user account. However, it is very likely, that this definition is about the *increase* of the privileges of the normal users, and not when mods want to *decrease* their privileges on some reason.

Mods I've talked about it<sup>*</sup> categorically denied that they would use any socks, although he did not make clear that they would be allowed it, if they would want to.

So what is the case? Are they allowed to use secondary accounts or not?

<sup>*</sup><sub>These are in long-deleted comment chats, I have no way to find/cite them.</sub>

Comment: It doesn't look like it's *illegal*: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/352680/798831

Comment: @Ollie If I understand the answers well, mod1 says "yes, but problematic". Mod2 says "no, and problematic". The levels above the mods did not react. I am not sure if it is a dupe, but I think it does not answer my question.

Comment: Also:    https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/269600/282094

Comment: @Rob That is an induvidual case about a blatant mod power misuse (if it is true. I think likely it is not. Anyways we have no way to know that, because SE would silently de-mod the mod and no one will ever know the details). This question is about the legality of the mods *decreasing* their own privileges.